# Cards with Modal always load the 1st object

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to apply Bootstrap Modal to a list (Card-Columns) of Cards but the popup always loads the content of the 1st Card.

Below my List Component:

```
<div
    class="card-columns"
    infiniteScroll
    [infiniteScrollDistance]="0.3"
    [infiniteScrollThrottle]="300"
    (scrolled)="onScrollDown()">
  <div *ngFor="let object of objects">
    <app-object [object]="object" (click)="tempObject=object" />
<!-- MODAL MOVED HERE -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalClass" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">{{ tempObject.title }}</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="{{ tempObject.imagePath }}" id="modalImg">
          <p id="modalText"> {{ tempObject.description }}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Get Object</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

List Class:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { Object } from './object.model';
import { ObjectService } from './object.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-object-list',
  templateUrl: './object-list.component.html'
})
export class ObjectListComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() categoriesToDisplay: Array<string>;

objects: Object[];
originalObjects: Object[];
tempObject : Object;

constructor(private objectService: ObjectService){}

ngOnInit() {
  this.objectService.getObjects()
   .subscribe(
    (objects: Object[]) => {
      this.originalObjects = objects;
      this.objects = objects;
    }
  );
 }

 applyFiltersToList(event) {
   this.objects = this.originalObjects.filter(d => event.includes(d.category));
  }

  onScrollDown () {
    console.log('scrolled down!!')
  }

}
```

And the Object Component:

```
<div class="card" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalClass">
<img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ object.imagePath }}" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">{{ object.title }}</h4>
        <p class="card-text">{{ object.description }}</p>
        <p class="added">Added <span id="when-added">{{ object.addedAt }}</span>
        </p>
        <a target="_blank" href="{{ object.url }}" class="btn btn-info">Get Object</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Object Class:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

import { Object } from './object.model';
import { ObjectService } from './object.service'

@Component({
  selector:'app-object',
  templateUrl: './object.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./object.component.css']
})
export class ObjectComponent{
  @Input() object: Object;

  constructor(private objectService: ObjectService,
          private router: Router,
          private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

 showDetails(id: string) {
 this.router.navigate([id], { relativeTo: this.route});
}
```

}

My List of Object Component is shown correctly, i.e., all the objects with correct information and the Modal works for all of them. However, when the popup loads, the information in there (object.title, object.descriptions, etc..) is always from the first object in the list.

Any ideas why does it load the information from the 1st object, rather than the one that was clicked?

Thanks

EDIT: UPdated based on the response given by @dimson d. Because the tempObject variable is only created when clicking in one of the objects, the initial load of the list fail. Once one is clicked, the modal id displayed correctly for all of the objects.

EDIT2: Solved by initializing tempObjects variable so it allows the list to get created. once the button is clicked, this variable will get object details.

Comment: How did you reference 'object' in Object component? with @Input ?

Comment: @Vega Yes.

export class ObjectComponent{
  @Input() object: Object;
}

Comment: Before <app-object....> put {{object.title}} to test if it gets correctly all other 'objects' and tell me please

Comment: It does display object.title corretly for all the objects in the list:

    <div *ngFor="let object of objects">
    {{object.title}}
    <app-object [object]="object" (click)="tempObject=object"></app-object>

Comment: Ok, that's already good, could you now replace <app-object ...> in the parent component view by the child view content?

Comment: It is just for debugging purposes. Do you change @Input value somewhere in your code?

Comment: I don't think that value is changed anywhere else. I'll update my original post with the classes to give more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bootstrap show you first modal from dom. no need to render a lot of modals. when you click button: (click)="tempObject = object" and your modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalClass" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">{{ tempObject.title }}</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <img src="{{ tempObject.imagePath }}" id="modalImg">
                            <p id="modalText"> {{ tempObject.description }}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Get tempObject</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. My problem with this solution is that I need to render the list of objects initially, which will fail as tempObject is undefined until the button is clicked. After the first click everything works fine, and the modal is indeed open with the correct object.

Comment: Problem solved. All I had to do was initialize tempObject so it exists when the list of objects is created and once the button is clicked, it will get overwritten with the actual object details.